# Expo - overriding target API level with expo-build-properties

Tags: expo

I've added an override to my `app.config.js` file like the example [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/), it looks like this under `plugins`:

```
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          android: {
            compileSdkVersion: 31,
            targetSdkVersion: 31,
            buildToolsVersion: "31.0.0",
          },
        },
      ]
```

but when I build with eas build and upload my `aab` file to the play store, it still complains about the target level:

> Your app currently targets API level 30 and must target at least API
> level 31 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for
> security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at
> least 31.

Am I using this library incorrectly?

Comment: Could you get this resolved? And, how did you resolve it?

Comment: @EdorLinus unfortunately I did not, ended up upgrading the SDK.